# Show that $f_ng_n \to fg$ in $B(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

> If $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ in $B(X)$, show that $f_ng_n \to fg$ in $B(X)$.

Note that given a set $X$, $B(X)$ is the vector space of all bounded, real-valued functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ and we supply $B(X)$ with the sup-norm $||f||_{\infty} = \sup\limits_{x \in X}|f(x)|$.

---

Given that  $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ in $B(X)$; which is precisely $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0$ and $||g_n-g||_{\infty} \to 0$. Thus we can find some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $$||f_n-f||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2||g_n||_{\infty}} \ \ \ and \ \ \ ||g_n-g||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2||f||_{\infty}}, \ \ \ \forall n\geq N. $$ Then we may compute the following: $$||f_{n}g_{n}-fg||_{\infty} \leq ||f_{n}g_{n}-fg_{n}||_{\infty} + ||fg_{n}-fg||_{\infty} \leq ||f_{n}-f||_{\infty}||g_n||_{\infty}+||g_{n}-g||_{\infty}||f||_{\infty}.$$ Therefore, $||f_{n}g_{n}-fg||_{\infty} < \epsilon$ so  $||f_{n}g_{n}-fg||_{\infty} \to 0$. It follows that $f_ng_n \to fg$ in $B(X)$.

Is this a correct argument for this problem? There was a lot of attention to detail when setting up and performing the triangle inequality, so I just want to be sure.

Comment: In the equation after "Then we may compute the following" the first term in the final bound should be $||f_n-f||_\infty ||g_n||_\infty$. You might also want to make clear that since $g_n \rightarrow g$ in norm, the norms $||g_n||$ are uniformly bounded and this is why an estimate of the form $||f_n-f||_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{2||g_n||}$ for all sufficiently large $n$, is possible.

Comment: Notice that $g_n$ may be identically zero and thus $\|g_n\|$ can be zero, so dividing by it will not be possible.

Comment: @jonathanHole - I figured this would be the problem, what if I defined $G = \sup_n||g_n||_{\infty}$ such that $||f_n - f||_{\infty} < \frac{\epsilon}{2G}$? Would that fix the error?

Comment: Yes, certainly!

Comment: @JonathanHole Awesome! Thank you for your feedback and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since $f_n\to f$, in the $\infty-$ norm, then for $\varepsilon=1$, there exists an $N$, such that for $n>N$,
$$
\|f_n-f\|<1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \|f_n\|< \|f\|+1.
$$
Hence
$$
\|f_n\| \le M=\max\{\|f\|+1, \|f_1\|,\ldots,\|f_N\|\}.
$$

Therefore
$$
\|f_ng_n-fg\|\le \|f_ng_n-f_ng\|+\|f_ng-fg\|\le \|g\|\|f_n-f\|+\|f_n\|\|g_n-g\|\\ \le 
\|g\|\|f_n-f\|+M\|g_n-g\|\to 0.
$$